# How to set up local server for development?

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

I have a computer that's running Windows 7, that I do most of my development on.  I have a spare laptop running Ubuntu.  They are both connected to the same wifi, and I'm developing in Rails.  Is there a way that I can use my spare laptop (Ubuntu) as a local server for development and testing that I would be able to connect to through my other computer (Windows 7)?

If it's not possible, how would I use my computer (Windows 7) as a local server for testing in Rails?  I have XAMPP installed, I just don't really know how to use it.

Answer (score 8):

First Install LAMP in Ubuntu. This is one of the thousands of links that explain How to do it.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Second Add Sites to Ubuntu Server. Again this is one of the many links that explain how to do it.
http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/07/how-to-configure-apache-linux/comment-page-1/#comment-1984

Finally open your server only locally,I mean Localhost for your home network. To do that edit the file  */etc/hosts*  and add at the end of the file

```
127.0.0.1  mysite
```

replace "mysite" for the name of your site and reload apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

You can access to *http://mysite* from any computer in your home network

Comment: Thank you so much!  I suppose I need to have Ubuntu Server installed, and not Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: Though, it gives me an error when I try to access the website.  Firefox tells me: "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.".