# Do I need a domain to set up an Apache server?

Tags: php, apache, debian, hosting

I'm trying to configure an Apache server but I'm totally new to this.

Do I need to pay for hosting/a web domain to configure Apache?

I just want to run PHP on Debian but I need Apache first I think.

Comment: Yes, `Apache`, a web server, is needed to deliver your content. You can set up `Apache` on local server and start working on your app. And, of course, if you want to go live, you'll need to buy hosting/domain to set up your application.

Comment: You can install the Apache Web Server on your local machine and learn how to configure it. Then you don't need to pay for hosting/a web domain.

Comment: Could you try running the following tutorial of setting up Apache, PHP, MariaDB on Debian, and see if that works for you? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-up-a-lamp-server-on-debian-10-buster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up local server for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276916/how-to-set-up-local-server-for-development)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAMPP. It hosts an apache server on localhost.

For a custom domain name, you need to pay, but you can use NOIP and port forwarding to make your XAMPP apache server public, but for a custom DNS you need to pay them...

You can also buy a domain by a hosting service, like one.com.

https://apachefriends.org

https://noip.com

https://one.com

Answer (score 0):

You can add domain you want in hosts file and use it in apache.

```
127.0.0.1 my-super-domain.com
```